# SQL Statement on a history table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’ve looked around for an answer and haven’t found one, and there might not be one.
I have a situation where I have a history record for changes to record in another table.

Example

```
RecordId | mainTID | DateAdded | V1 |  V2 | V3 <br>
1 | 1 | 1/1/2020 | 1 | 1 | 1<br>
2 | 1 | 1/2/2020 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
3 | 1 | 2/1/2020 | 0 | 2 | 0<br>
4 | 1 | 2/2/2020 | 0 | 0 | 2<br>
5 | 2 | 1/1/2020 | 2 | 1 | 1<br>
6 | 2 | 1/5/2020 | 2 | 2 | 2<br>
7 | 2 | 1/7/2020 | 1 | 2 | 0<br>
8 | 2 | 2/8/2020 | 2 | 2 | 2<br>
9 | 3 | 1/5/2020 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
```

I need to get this data via date range, but I only want the last record for each mainTID.  Example if I did a query for 1/1/2020 to 1/7/2020 I would get

```
RecordId | mainTID | DateAdded | V1 |  V2 | V3 <br>
2 | 1 | 1/2/2020 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
7 | 2 | 1/7/2020 | 1 | 2 | 0<br>
9 | 3 | 1/5/2020 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
```

Ultimate goal would be a count on the value columns so I would get

```
Counts  | V1 |  V2 | V3 <br>
2 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
1 | 1 | 2 | 0<br>
```

I need to get this data via date range, but I only want the last record for each mainTID.  Example if I did a query for 1/1/2020 to 2/8/2020 I would get

```
RecordId | mainTID | DateAdded | V1 |  V2 | V3 <br>
4 | 1 | 2/2/2020 | 0 | 0 | 2<br>
8 | 2 | 2/8/2020 | 2 | 2 | 2<br>
9 | 3 | 1/5/2020 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
```

again goal would be a count on the value columns so I would get

```
Counts  | V1 |  V2 | V3 <br>
1 | 0 | 0 | 1<br>
1 | 2 | 2 | 2<br> 
1 | 0 | 1 | 1<br>
```

Is there a way to get these results with 1 SQL statement: FYI: I am using MSSQL 2019 if that would make a difference

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.dateadded = (select max(t2.dateadded)
                     from t t2
                     where t2.mainTID = t.mainTID and
                           t2.dateadded between @date1 and @date2
                    );
```

Comment: Great. I just added group by and counts, and it worked!!
I tried everything before this but this line was the difference
where T1.DateAdded = (select max(T2.DateAdded)
I feel stupid I didn't figure that out

Thank you